# C++ Game Development Code Error

Tags: c++

The error is it supposed to return a value for the number of GOLD_PIECES the leader has taken. But, it always returns the value 0 no matter what I do. This is a C++ beginner level code, So anyone with some C++ background can help me to solve this problem. The problem is in the 41st line (two lines above the return 0;) cout << leader << " held on to the extra " << (GOLD_PIECES % survivors);

```
// Lost Fortune
// A personalized adventure

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    const int GOLD_PIECES = 900;
    int adventurers, killed, survivors;
    string leader;

    //get the information
    cout << "Welcome to Lost Fortune\n\n";
    cout << "Please enter the following for your personalized adventure\n";

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> adventurers;

    cout << "Enter a number, smaller than the first: ";
    cin >> killed;

    survivors = adventurers - killed;

    cout << "Enter your last name: ";
    cin >> leader;

    //tell the story
    cout << "\nA brave group of " << adventurers << " set out on a quest ";
    cout << "-- in search of the lost treasure of the Ancient Dwarves. ";
    cout << "The group was led by that legendary rogue, " << leader << ".\n";

    cout << "\nAlong the way, a band of marauding ogres ambushed the party. ";
    cout << "All fought bravely under the command of " << leader;
    cout << ", and the ogres were defeated, but at a cost. ";
    cout << "Of the adventurers, " << killed << " were vanquished, ";
    cout << "leaving just " << survivors << " in the group.\n";

    cout << "\nThe party was about to give up all hope. ";
    cout << "But while laying the deceased to rest, ";
    cout << "they stumbled upon the buried fortune. ";
    cout << "So the adventurers split " << GOLD_PIECES << " gold pieces.";
    cout << leader << " held on to the extra " << (GOLD_PIECES % survivors);
    cout << " pieces to keep things fair of course.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug, debug, debug!

Comment: Please use a more descriptive question title.

Comment: In Which line you are getting `0`?

Comment: I think `(GOLD_PIECES % survivors)` is returning `0` value. What input you are passing (`adventurers` and `killed`)?

Comment: The 900 GOLD_PIECES are shared among the adventurers equally. The share of the killed adventurers is taken by the leader alongside his own share. What this code need is to find how much GOLD_PIECES the leader has taken.

Comment: I think `GOLD_PIECES` should equally distribute among all `surviors` and remaining coin will be taken by `leader` .So for this replace `(GOLD_PIECES % survivors)` with `(GOLD_PIECES / survivors) + (GOLD_PIECES % survivors)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I remember this book. It is what started me on the great path to C++ programming! Anyways, to answer your question. Are you sure you are not passing a variable that 900 is divisible by? Please try 8 and 1 as the first two numbers entered and then try the program again. When I did this program last year I ran into no problems with the code out of the textbook. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank You! Now I can proceed to the second chapter.